# Prove, by logical reasoning, rather than by formula, the following permutation identities

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations, combinations

The formula would have been useful but I am not really good at logical reasoning especially in permutations so I need help from you guys to identify errors in my answer (as well as give hints for part b and e)

> **(a) $n_r=(n-1)_r+r(n-1)_{r-1}$**

$n_r$ is the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from $n$ and then arrange them. Now, let us fix an object $a$ from the given $n$. Now, there are two cases: **Case 1**: when selected $r$ objects do not contain $a$. This is given by $(n-1)_r$ **Case 2:** when the $r$ objects contain $a$. Then, number of ways is then $(n-1)_{r-1}$ and then $r$ places to insert the $a$ so total $r(n-1)_{r-1}$. Since, both cases are Mutually Exclusive, we have $n_r=(n-1)_r+r(n-1)_{r-1}$ proved.

> **(b) $n_n=n_{n-1}$**

I am not getting this. I need help on this one to proceed.

> **(c) $n_n=n\cdot(n-1)_{n-1}$**

$n_n$ is the number of ways to select and permute $n$ objects from $n$ which is simply $n!$. Now, fix an object $a$ from $n$ and then number of ways to select and permute remaining $(n-1)$ are $(n-1)_{n-1}$ and then $n$ places to insert $a$ which thus becomes $n(n-1)_{n-1}=n!=n_n$  proved.

> **(d) $\binom{n}{r}r_r=n_r$**

$\binom{n}{r}$ is the number of ways to select $r$ objects from $n$. Multiplying it by $r_r$ gives us the number of ways to select and **arrange** $r$ objects from $n$, which is the same as $n_r$. Proved.

> **(e) $r\binom{n}{r}=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$**

**Update:** After Kevin's answer, I figured out that $r\binom{n}{r}$ is selecting $r$ objects from $n$ and then taking a special object from the $r$, which is equivalent to first selecting the special object and then the remaining $r-1$ from the $n-1$ objects left $= n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$. proved.

---

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, could you elaborate on the (e) part...I didn't really get it.

Comment: Never mind, got it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as this sounds, I'd say the best way to look at this sort of question is through examples; let's try permutations of a $3$ element set (since $2$ is too small and $4$ too big). For ABC, we get: (ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB, CBA). Now let's look at $2$-permutations of the same set. We get: (AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB). From here, you can see the correspondence. It's just a matter of creating an involution to show that both count the same thing.

For (e), you should ask yourself: what is each side counting? On the left, you know what $\binom{n}{r}$ counts: size $r$ subsets of an $n$ element set. You can think of the $r$ as then picking an element of that subset. Overall, it counts size $r$ subsets of an $n$ element set with a special element in that subset. How, then, does the right side count the same thing? On the left, we found the subset first, then the special element. Can you see how the right side reverses that order?

Comment: Thanks! I have understood the (e) part, but not part (b) yet :( For part (b), I can see the correspondence is that I can remove a character from any particular position (left,middle,right) from each of the original permutations then I get one element of the new permutation. But how can I prove that there will not be any duplicates in the new permutation by this method? (i.e. i may not get the same element of the new permutation from two different strings of the original permutation?)

Comment: Fix the position that you remove the element from (let's say last). So $f(x)$ takes a permutation $x$ of length $n$ and returns a permutation $y$ of length $n-1$ by removing the last entry. $f(x)$ is well defined on the set of permutations of an $n$ set, so you just need to show that it is surjective and injective. (1/2)

Comment: For any length $n-1$ permutation of an $n$ set, I can add the missing character to the end to get an $n$ permutation, so it is surjective. If two $n$ permutations have the same image by $f$, then their first $n-1$ characters (the image) are the same, and so their last characters must be the same as well, since there's only one character with which they can end. (2/2)